# How to alert data when bootstrap5 dropdown menu is closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to alert data when Bootstrap5 Dropdown menu is closed but cannot get it to work.
Below is what i have tried

```
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> 




$('.dropdown-menu').on("hide.bs.dropdown", function () {

   alert('Dropdown Menu is closed');               
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because you are trying to run the function on ul elements, where as you should be running the eventlistenner on button element. I would suggest you to use id on that particular dropdown element.

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on("hide.bs.dropdown", function () {
   alert('Dropdown Menu is closed');               
});
```

Here is the working [example](https://codepen.io/sohebm/pen/ZErOKzG) for your code. I have just added the id to the button element.